# Can I transform a Stream<List<X>> to a Stream<X>?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Is this possible (pseudo-Java):

```
someList = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4]
];
Stream<List<X>> a = someList.stream();
Stream<X> b = a.whatever(...);
assert b.collect(list).equals([1,2,3,4]);
```

Put more generally, is there an operation on a stream that can increase the number of elements in the stream (rather than decrease, as `filter` does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `flatMap` does that.

```
Stream<X> b = someList.stream().flatMap(l -> l.stream());
```

Assuming that `someList` is a `List<List<X>>`, `flatMap` would flatten all the elements of the internal lists into a single Stream.

Comment: You could use a method reference `.flatMap(List::stream)`

Comment: So simple. Yet I didn't find it because I didn't know *flatten* is the right term here.